# Hide Status of Developer Options

Tags: developer-options, android-13, oxygenos

Is it possible to hide the status (if dev options are on/off) of my developer options to certain apps?

There are some apps which force you to turn dev options off, and I don't want to turn them off because animation speed is set to default then and that's waaaaay too slow.

Comment: Hiding is possible on rooted device using Xposed. I don't think that the developer settings you have changed will be reverted if you disable develop options, so if you only want to change e.g. animation speed change it and then disable developer options.

Comment: @Robert sadly they do change, I tested it. That's the only reason why I'm here to ask the question if I can bypass that check. Ok so rooting and xposed is a lot of work just for one app

Comment: If it is just one app you could try to decompile it using apktool and patch it to remove the developer options check and then rebuild the APK, align and sign it.